# Double variable outputs 32767 always instead of user input

Tags: c++, variables, types, output, double

I'm writing code that asks about rainfall each month, then outputs yearly total, monthly average, min, and max rain month (index). My code is almost complete, except that instead of outputting the max value the output always shows the max range of the variable type 32767 (e.g. if rain is 70mm and maximum, console shows 32767 always). Thanks for your help. I'm self-learning.

I have tried the following code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int numMonths = 3;
    double monthlyRain[numMonths]={0,0,0};
    string monthName[numMonths]= {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar"};
    int count = 0;
    int indexWettest = 0;
    int indexDriest = 0;
    double  yearTotal=0, monthlyAverage=0;
    double monthHighest;
    double monthLowest;

    monthLowest = monthlyRain[0];
    monthHighest = monthlyRain[0];


    // enter monthly rain;
    for (int count=0; count < numMonths; count++){
        cout << "Please enter amount of rain in " << monthName[count] << endl;
        cin >> monthlyRain[count];
    }


    // print month and corresponding rain amount;
    cout << "Month --- Rain(mm)" << endl;
    for (int count = 0; count < numMonths; count++){
        cout << monthName[count] << " " << monthlyRain[count] << endl;
    }


    // calculate year total;
    for (int count = 0; count < numMonths; count++){
        yearTotal += monthlyRain[count];
    }

    // calculate average monthly rainfall;
    monthlyAverage = yearTotal/numMonths;

    // find month with lowest rainfall;


    // find month with highest rainfall;

    for (int count = 0; count < numMonths; count++){    
        if (monthlyRain[count] > monthHighest){
            monthHighest = monthlyRain[count+1];
            indexWettest = count;
        }
    }


// PROBLEM IS HERE!;
    for (int count = 0; count < numMonths; count++){
        if (monthlyRain[count] < monthLowest){
            monthLowest = monthlyRain[count];
            indexDriest = count;

        }

    }

    cout << "Total yearly rain fall is: " << yearTotal << endl;
    cout << "Average monthly rainfall is: " << monthlyAverage << endl;
    cout << "The driest month is " <<  monthName[indexDriest] << " with rain amount of  " << monthLowest << endl;
    cout << "The wettest month is " <<  monthName[indexWettest] << " with rain amount of  " << monthHighest << endl; //<< monthName[indexWettest];

return 0;
}
```

Expected result is the user input.

Comment: You might want to enable some compiler warnings, see [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/lfA62S), this can indicate several bugs in your code

Comment: You're initializing `monthLowest` and `monthHighest` with `monthlyRain[0]`, which by itself is not initialized, hence the remaining of your program yields undefined behavior.

Comment: @goodvibration Nitpick: undefined behavior is not limited to "the remainder of the program". Since it is unavoidable to arrive at the problematic assignment, the entire program has undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I added initial values to variables and the array (see revised code). But the problem persists. The problem occurs only in the last loop code.

Comment: also read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

Read compiler warnings.

```
main.cpp:35:19: warning: 'yearTotal' may be used uninitialized in this function [- 
Wmaybe-uninitialized]

yearTotal += monthlyRain[count];
```

Line that declares `yearTotal` should be double yearTotal **= 0**;

Same with other variables. Always initialize them.

Comment: Can you explain how to enable compiler warnings?

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: The most commonly used ones? MSVC, GCC, Clang?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=vs-2019 and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: @Michael Chourdakis: initialization didn't work. The problem is still there in the last loop. Could it be because I'm using the variable count in both loops for min and max rain?